# Displaying same image when app is run two times

Tags: java, android

I am building a small android application and i am new to android.
I have two images,one with flower and other with animal.
When i run my app first flower will be displayed and when i press the flower it should toggle to an animal.Now animal image will be displayed. If i go back and run my app again i am getting the image of a flower displayed.
But i want the animal image only to be displayed.
Nothing should change once i go back and run again.

How can i do this,a code for this in java would be helpful 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: i want a java code so that i ca understand better

Comment: ohh well. can you try it yourself first and then come to SO.

Comment: I tried it but every time flower image was displaying when i run each time but i want to restore the animal image. I am not knowing about that.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
You can check the activity lifecycle here :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

When you go to the home screen, the onPause() method is called.
When you resume the activity and it has focus (it is visible) the onResume() method is called. 
Your member class attributes are not modified. If you declare an attribute to "TRUE" and you modify it in the code to "FALSE", if you resume the application it is always to "FALSE".

Hovewer, you have to be careful ! 
When your application has not the focus (i.e. you can see it in the multitask manager), the system can detroy the activity to free memory. If you don't save the state of the activity, it will be recreate as default.

This is why you should use this : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

You have to save a boolean to know if it is the first or the second image and restore the good image in the onRestoreInstanceState().

Something like that should work.

```
//change this to false when you change the image
public boolean isFirstImage = true;
public ImageView image;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("isFirstImage", isFirstImage);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myview);
    image.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flower));
    image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isFirstImage) {
                image.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flower));
                isFirstImage = false;
            } else {
                image.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.animal));
                isFirstImage = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void onResume() {
    if (isFirstImage) {
        image.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flower));
    } else {
        image.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.animal));
    }
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Restore state members from saved instance
    isFisrtImage = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isFirstImage");


    if (isFirstImage) {
        image.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flower));
    } else {
        image.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.animal));
    }
}
```

Comment: can i the java code for this . I can understand much better

Comment: how to use onRestoreInstanceState in my case.

Comment: Iam getting confused with this,since iam new iam not able to understand in one shot.can u please consider two image and give me a complete code of it please

Comment: savedInstanceState.putInt("isFirstImage", isFirstImage);

Comment: here for isFirstImage it is displaying as it should be int value

Comment: In savedInstanceState.putInt("isFirstImage",isFirstImage) it is showing an error that FirstImage should be an int and not boolean.

Comment: it is putBoolean not putInt sorry !

Answer (score 0):

you can use SharedPreferences to save the state of your images, by saving some boolean value and whenever you return to your activity just for the value and according to that you set the image.

follow the link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: SharedPreference is heavy for that. Especially when you have method directly from the SDK for this kind of situation :p But it should work too !